# Choosing whether or not to display a module in sublinks of a Joomla component

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.5

In Joomla 1.5, you can set modules to display on certain menus and not display on the others. When you set Joomla to display a module on a menu going to a component, it displays that module on all the possible links inside that component. Is there anyway I can change this feature. Is there a way that I can decide which module shows on some sublinks without creating menus that direct me to those sublinks.

I hope my question is clear. If not pls, ask for clarification and I would do that gladly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider using: http://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/advancedmodulemanager

It gives you enough options to display modules on very specific pages / scenarios like yours.